# Extract .osm data appears in axonometric on QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I'm working with QGIS 2.18.

1. I extract .osm data from the site.
   name : vernon.osm
2. Then i transformed it in a data base file : vernon.osm.db
3. Finally i used spatialite to make it appearing on QGIS. polylines and polygons appear but in axonometric (like in the picture)

[image]

The main point of all this is to export the datas in .dxf to use on autocad.

In axonometric it's not exportable.

Answer (score 2):

The data view is not axonometric. It is distorted because osm data is in degrees, and one degree in latitude is not the same distance as one degree of longitude for most parts of the world.

You have to save the data in a projected CRS (like the UTM zone for your part of the world) to display the data correctly.

Comment: Well you are my savior :)  Merci beaucoup!